# jQuery side menu toggle change gyphicon on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jQuery side menu toggle.

```js
$('#open').click(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify').toggleClass('glyphicon-remove');
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
})

$(document).click(function(e) {
  var sidebar = $(".sidebar, #open");

  if (!sidebar.is(e.target) && sidebar.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('#open').find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify').toggleClass('glyphicon-remove');
    sidebar.removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<li class="topHeaderMenu leftMenu listMenu" id="open">
  <div class="listMenuDiv"><i class="glyphicon2 glyphicon-align-justify"></i></div>
</li>

<div class="sidebar">
  sidebar content
</div>
```

So, when I click `#open` then the sidebar will open.
The question is how to make the `glyphicon-align-justify` change to `glyphicon-remove` if sidebar open 
and make `glyphicon-remove` to `glyphicon-align-justify` if sidebar close
and how to keep `glyphicon-align-justify` on document click(the current if I click outside/body it will change to `glyphicon-remove`)

Comment: Please add the visual display using code snippet.

Comment: What problem are you facing??

Comment: here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfehs6bg/65/

Comment: Try to click outside, you can see the glyphicon-remove will show even the sidebar not open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your script

```
$('#open').click(function()
    {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify').toggleClass('glyphicon-remove');
        $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    })

    $(document).click(function(e)
    {
  if($(".sidebar.active").length > 0){


        var sidebar = $(".sidebar, #open");

        if(!sidebar.is(e.target) && sidebar.has(e.target).length === 0)
        {
            $('#open').find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify').toggleClass('glyphicon-remove');
            sidebar.removeClass('active');
        }
     }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Working perfect (y)